# call javascript function from hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

```
function getValue()
{
    alert(document.getElementById('user').value);
    return true
}

<a href="my.html" onclick="return getvalue()">Go</a>
```

When user click on hyperlink, before it redirect to `my.html`, it should invoke `getValue()` function, which will display username from textbox, whose id is `user`.

Comment: seems like you answering , not asking

Comment: but, it is not working :( I mean, alert box isn't showing

Comment: `getvalue()` <==> `getValue()`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: What element is `user`? If it's not an `input`, it won't have a `.value` property (though @Juhana's comment is probably the answer).

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) works. You can set it to preserve the error log even when you navigate to another page so you'll see what the error was when you click the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to:

```
<a href="my.html" onclick="return getValue()">Go</a>
```

javascript is case sensitive!

Comment: Nice copypasting skill.

Comment: @Cthulhu: perhaps, but this is likely the answer, and if Juhana decided not to post an answer (for whatever reason), then copy-pasting's fine. At least that way the question *gets* an answer (as opposed to a comment-thread, which is not the purpose of the comments).

Comment: my language is not English, because this i cant explain to @Cthulhu. But "DavidThomas" explain that very well. thanks.

Comment: Why do you think I meant it the bad way? May be I was just being jealous I could not copypast it earlier? :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, so you must correct che call function in the a tag:

```
function getValue()
{
alert(document.getElementById('user').value);
return true
}

<a href="my.html" onclick="return getValue()">Go</a>
```

there must also be the element "user" , otherwise document.getElementById('user').value cause an error